# Preserving file owner/perms upon "edit" in PHPExcel

Tags: php, phpexcel

I'm very new to PHPExcel, and did a search for my question, but feel it hasn't been asked/answered sufficiently.

When I open a workbook using PHPExcel (using CreateReader), and then modify one of the worksheets, and write it back out (using CreateWriter, same file name), the files new owner is www-data, and the perms are 644.  Originally, I was the owner, and the perms were 755.

Is this a function of PHPExcel, or my Apache/PHP stack?

Comment: Take a look at `chown` and `chmod` php functions. They might be able to help you reset the owner and permissions.

Comment: Apache does so. www-data is the user which runs Apache. Since he runs the script he becomes owner

Comment: Nothing to do with PHPExcel, everything to do with PHP/Apache